# checkcolumn get count

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

In a table column I have check boxes which gives me indicator whether i make any changes in it, I want to show the changes made in the message text. e.g (000 unsaved changes). I have used xtype:'checkcolumn'. How to get count for changes i made in check box.

```
{
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'Select',
            align:'center',
            dataIndex: 'mapped',
            flex:1,
            listeners : 
                        {
                            checkchange : function(column, recordIndex, checked) 
                                        {
                                            alert(checked);
                                            //or send a request
                                        } 
                        }

        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using these four store methods:

- [getModifiedRecords()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getModifiedRecords) - Gets all records added or updated since the last commit. columns
- [getNewRecords( )](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getNewRecords) - Gets all new records.
- [getUpdatedRecords( )](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getUpdatedRecords) - Returns all Model instances that have been updated in the Store but not yet synchronized with the Proxy.
- [getRemovedRecords( )](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getRemovedRecords) - Returns any records that have been removed from the store but not yet destroyed on the proxy.

maybe something like this:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('yourStore'),
    modified = store.getUpdatedRecords(),
    count = modified.lenght;
console.log(count + ' changes made');
```

Comment: Please provide with my code example. I want to show something like "000 changes made" as a header to table in extjs

Comment: so I guess there is no modified records?

Comment: doesn't matter if there were no modified records it would have return empty array with length 0. in what line you get the error?

Comment: {
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
             header: 'Select',
    align:'center',
          dataIndex: 'mapped',
       flex:1,
    listeners : 
       {
        checkchange : function(column, recordIndex, checked) 
           {
            var store = Ext.getStore('abc'),
             modified = store.getUpdatedRecords(),
             count = modified.lenght;
             
             alert(store);
             //console.log(count + ' changes made');

           } 
       }

   }

Comment: if you can create example in jsfiddle.com with what doesn't work.